# How can I align an <h2> box?

Tags: html, css

I wrapped an  tag with a gray border, and for some reason I can't align it.

`text-align:center;` isn't working.

The other things work like `width:155px;`

So what's wrong?

Comment: Use display: inline-block;

Comment: Without code, it is usually hard to guess what the exact problem is, and guessing for answers is usually the only thing anybody can do. If you provide a piece of code of your previous attempts, it will be a lot easier to understand what the exact problem you're having is. That piece of code can even be code that doesn't work at all, because it would still give a better idea of what you are trying to do exactly.

Comment: Put your code in a codepen (http://codepen.io/pen/) and link it up here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to do that.

The first could be make a auto-position style like this:

`<h2 style="margin: 0 auto; width:50%; ">The Subtitile</h2>`

This will positioning your h2 block in the middle of screen. The best should be use a CSS in a separated file.

I hope my aswer help you.